# Не видно sd-карту при переключении на su

Tags: android, файловая-система, su

При переключении на суперпользователя пропадает sd-карта из mount.

```
u0_a87@lcsh92_wet_jb9:/ $ mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid
1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=100
 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000
0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid
1000 0 0
/emmc@android /system ext4 ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatim
,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@usrdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,d
scard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,di
card,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /mnt/cd-rom iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0
/emmc@protect_f /protect_f ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,no
time,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@protect_s /protect_s ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,no
time,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse rw,context=u:object_r:sdcar
_internal:s0,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=10
3,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard0 vfat rw,dirsyn
,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,
mask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859
1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nos
id,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask
0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,sh
rtname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,us
r_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
u0_a87@lcsh92_wet_jb9:/ $ su
root@lcsh92_wet_jb9:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid
1000 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=750,gid
1000 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=100
 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000
0 0
/emmc@android /system ext4 ro,seclabel,noatime,noauto_da_al
oc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@usrdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,d
scard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,di
card,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /mnt/cd-rom iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0
/emmc@protect_f /protect_f ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,no
time,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@protect_s /protect_s ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,no
time,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse rw,context=u:object_r:sdcar
_internal:s0,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=10
3,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
root@lcsh92_wet_jb9:/ #
```